# Drupal 9, Url segment conditionals in Twig

Tags: twig, drupal-9

Url: example.com/urlsegment1/urlsegment2

How do you achieve the same as the below PHP code with Twig in Drupal 9. I specifically need the code to work within [paragraph.html.twig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/paragraphs/theming-paragraphs-in-drupal-8) templates. I want to be able to write conditionals based off the url segment.

Conditional logic

```
IF urlsegment1 = X
DO A
ELSE
DO B
```

How to do it in PHP

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);

echo $uri_segments[0]; // for www.example.com/user/account you will get 'user'
```